dataframe_image error: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command (args) returned non-zero exit status 21
I have been using dataframe_image for a couple years and am stuck on an error that just occurred today. I am getting the following error when trying to run dfi.export (index axis hidden,fontsize and dpi specified) for a dataframe.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\david.clark\REPORT_TrendQuality\venv\lib\site-packages\dataframe_image\_screenshot.py", line 142, in take_screenshot
    self.generate_image_from_html(args)
  File "C:\Users\david.clark\REPORT_TrendQuality\venv\lib\site-packages\dataframe_image\_screenshot.py", line 150, in generate_image_from_html
    subprocess.run(executable=self.chrome_path, args=args, capture_output=True, check=True)
  File "C:\Users\david.clark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['--enable-logging', '--disable-gpu', '--headless', '--crash-dumps-dir=C:\\Users\\DAVID~1.CLA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpw370ybdw', '--force-device-scale-factor=2.0', '--window-size=1400,900', '--hide-scrollbars', '--screenshot=C:\\Users\\DAVID~1.CLA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpw370ybdw\\temp.png', 'C:\\Users\\DAVID~1.CLA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpw370ybdw\\temp.html']' returned non-zero exit status 21.

This seems to be occurring in _screenshot.py. I suspect it has something to do with the args for generate_image_from_html but have no clue what's wrong. I also wonder if it's due to any recent Chrome updates since I've had issues with that in the past. Anyone know what's going on here?
I ran the following code:
    metrics_df = metrics_df.style.hide(axis="index")
    dfi.export(metrics_df, '{}_{}_{}_trend_quality_table_1.png'.format(row['CDAP Env.'], row['Patient ID'], row['Cordella ID']),
               fontsize=10, dpi=200)

I was expecting a file named 'a_b_c_trend_quality_table_1.png' to appear in my working directory which would be an image of the metrics dataframe.

Solution (Credit: Andrews): I added the table_conversion argument to dfi.export. I believe the default was chrome and by changing this (I used matplotlib) the code worked.

Just got the same error in a different script so this error is likely not specific to the original script. I tried reinstalling dataframe_image and there's no change.

I think it's due to Chrome. You can change the table_conversion argument to something else.

This worked, thanks! I added the argument table_conversion="matplotlib" to the dfi.export command.

Big thanks for this one - this now worked for me: dfi.export(df_exporting, file_loc, table_conversion='matplotlib')

I had the same issue and change table_conversion to matplotlib change my table visualization. For those who need to keep the same table visualization, i found the solution here :
Subprocess doesn't save PDF file
replace '--headless' by '--headless=old'

@DavidClark: This solution seems to have been added in the latest release of dfi, see here. Latest version having been released on Oct 8, 2024: dataframe-image 0.2.5. So, upgrading is surely worth a try, if you didn't manage to implement this fix manually.

I had the same issue, also solved by table_convertion argument. Intresting, that this argument isn't mentioned in pandas documentation though the page exists.
I had to set table_convertion="selenium", because matplotlib ruined some of my table styles (maybe will be usefull for someone else)

I had the same issue and solved it as
table_convertion="celenium" not "selenium"...

Per the docs, "celenium" is an invalid value. I think you just caused it to fall back on the chrome default.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The problem is with your chrome setup, which is the default browser configuration for dfi.export(). If you have chrome installed, then it could just be a mismatch between your chrome version and the dataframe-image version.
That is why changing the table conversion parameter to one of the other values resolved your problem.
From the docs:

Current we provide 4 difference browser backend liberary: playwright,
html2image, selenium and chrome. The default is chrome.
chrome, which means convert image with your local chromium based
browser by command line.
html2image is a backup method for chrome, which use html2image.
playwright is a much more stable method, but you have to install
playwright first.
selenium is a method that use Firefox driver. Sometimes chrome will
make some breaking changes which break methods above, Firefox will be
a good backup. Not stable and hard to install. But can be installed in
Google Colab.

dfi.export(
    obj: pd.DataFrame,
    filename,
    fontsize=14,
    max_rows=None,
    max_cols=None,
    table_conversion: Literal[
        "chrome", "matplotlib", "html2image", "playwright", "selenium"
    ] = "chrome",
    chrome_path=None,
    dpi=None, # enlarge your image，default is 100，set it larger will get a larger image
    use_mathjax=False, # enable mathjax support， which means you can use latex in your dataframe
)

